# Selenium Webdriver: Obtaining the text from a <td> tag using xpath

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm struggling to obtain the "http://www.sportsuperstore.co.uk/leisure......" text from the following HTML using Xpath:

```
<tr>
<td class="form-label-text">Path: </td>
<td/>
<td>http://www.sportsuperstore.co.uk/leisure/store-information/article-1355816188279/</td>
</tr>
```

I need to to a getText() on the value and convert to String.  I've struggled so far using typical css and xpath selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data in the first `<td>` as a selector, and getting the text in the next sibling `<td>` skipping one empty `<td/>`:

```
//tr/td[@class='form-label-text'][contains(.,'Path:')]/following-sibling::td[2]/text()
```

You can also use `last()` if it's always the last `<td>` in the context:

```
//tr/td[@class='form-label-text'][contains(.,'Path:')]/following-sibling::td[last()]/text()
```